# group by function with complicated SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi

I have this Statement that select a sum of quantity ans Amounts of products from a big DataBase

```
  SELECT
        (SELECT Name FROM AD_Org WHERE AD_Org_ID = 1000001
        ) AS Org,
        (SELECT bp.Name FROM C_BPartner bp WHERE bp.C_BPARTNER_ID = 0
        ) AS Selected_Vendor,
        (SELECT MAX(bp.Name)
        FROM C_BPartner bp
        WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
          FROM M_Product_PO po
          WHERE bp.C_BPARTNER_ID =po.C_BPARTNER_ID
          AND po.M_PRODUCT_ID    = p.M_PRODUCT_ID
          AND po.ISCURRENTVENDOR ='Y'
          AND AD_Org_ID          = 1000001
          )
        )                                  AS Vendor,
        p.Value                            AS Value_Product,
        p.Name                             AS Name_Product,
        COALESCE( SUM(ol.QTYORDERED) , 0)  AS qty_bought ,
        COALESCE( SUM(ol.LINENETAMT) , 0)  AS Amount_bought ,
        COALESCE( SUM(ol2.QTYORDERED) , 0) AS qty_sales ,
        COALESCE( SUM(ol2.LINENETAMT) , 0) AS Amount_sales,
        bomOffQtyOnHand(p.M_PRODUCT_ID,
        (SELECT NVL(M_WAREHOUSE_ID,0) FROM AD_OrgInfo WHERE AD_Org_ID = 1000001
        ), NULL) AS STOCK,
        (SELECT Name FROM M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY pc WHERE pc.M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID =0
        ) AS Product_Category
      FROM M_Product p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN C_OrderLine ol
      ON (p.m_product_id = ol.m_product_id)
      INNER JOIN C_Order o
    ....
    ....

      WHERE (p.M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID =0
     ....
     ....
     )
 ORDER BY p.value,
        p.Nam
```

this statement give me always group function error

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

when i Put this lines to fix it it give another group by error

```
 GROUP BY SUM(ol.QTYORDERED) ,
SUM(ol.LINENETAMT),
SUM(ol2.QTYORDERED),
SUM(ol2.LINENETAMT),
 p.Value,
 p.name
```

error

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

I think I must put All the selected items in the group by so how can I put this

```
(SELECT Name FROM AD_Org WHERE AD_Org_ID = 1000001
        ) AS Org,
```

or this

```
 (SELECT MAX(bp.Name)
        FROM C_BPartner bp
        WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
          FROM M_Product_PO po
          WHERE 
          ....
          AND AD_Org_ID          = 1000001
          )
        )   AS Vendor,
```

in the `group by` or any other method to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aggregate with SUM here:

```
COALESCE( SUM(ol.QTYORDERED) , 0)  AS qty_bought ,
COALESCE( SUM(ol.LINENETAMT) , 0)  AS Amount_bought ,
COALESCE( SUM(ol2.QTYORDERED) , 0) AS qty_sales ,
COALESCE( SUM(ol2.LINENETAMT) , 0) AS Amount_sales,
```

So everything else (p.Value, p.Name, p.M_PRODUCT_ID) must be either in the GROUP BY clause or be aggregated, too ( e.g. MIN(p.Value) ).